# node.js readline: reading k lines at a time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, readline, large-files

I've been using Node.JS' builtin [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) library. I am doing some bulk processing of large CSV files. How do I read `k` lines at a time?

---

Here is a silly approach off-the-top of my head:

```
import { createInterface } from 'readline';
import { createReadStream } from 'fs';

const processLargeFile = (rl, k, callback) => {
    const a = [];
    const drainAndProcess = () => a.splice(0, a.length); // Dummy function

    rl.on('line', line => {
         a.push(line);
         a.length + 1 > k && drainAndProcess();  // Stupid approach
    });

    rl.on('error', error => callback(error));
    rl.on('end', () => callback(void 0, 'finished'));
};

processLargeFile(createInterface({input: createReadStream('huge_file.csv')}), 15,
                 (err, msg) => err == null ? console.info(msg) : throw err);
```

What's a better way of doing it? - Should I be emitting events and keeping count using [`%`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)? - Or something else?

Comment: Does it work? I don't see any inherent problem here. I'm assuming drainAndProcess will eventually call your callback with the array of lines, right? And why `a.length + 1 > k` instead of `a.length == k`?

Comment: `>` two reasons: 0) `>` is more efficient than `==` (at least in ASM?); and 1) if the count is incremented concurrently there may be discrepancies leaving a `batch size > k`. I have run the code yet, I wrote it in-situ. But yeah, is there a better way of doing it, without all this synchronicity?

Comment: _"I am doing some bulk processing of large CSV files"_. Wouldn't you rather use a streaming CSV parser (like [`fast-csv`](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv))?

Comment: @robertklep - Yeah I used fast-csv a couple of weeks ago, it worked but I didn't need any of its fancy features, when a simple `zip` and `.split('\t')` is all I needed.

Comment: There's really no reason to worry about race conditions like that. More than likely the readline library will wait for your callback inside of `rl.on` to return before creating another 'line' event IF another line is read before you have the chance to perform the operations on your array, which would also be unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Not super happy with this solution, but it works:

```
const raise = throwable => { throw throwable; };
const processTsv = (fname, callback) => {
    const processTsvLargeFile = (rl, k, callb) => {
        const a = [];
        let header;
        const drainAndProcess = cb => console.info(
            a.map(row => row.reduce((o, v, i) =>
                             Object.assign(o, { [header[i]]: v }), {})),
            '\nlen =', a.length) || a.splice(0, a.length) && cb();

        rl.on('line', line => {
            typeof header === 'undefined' ? header = line.split('\t')
                                          : a.push(line.split('\t'));
            a.length + 1 > k && drainAndProcess(er => er != null && rl.emit(er));
        });

        rl.on('error', error => callb(error));
        rl.on('end', () => drainAndProcess(err => err != null ? callb(err)
                                                  : callb(void 0, 'finished')));
    };

    processTsvLargeFile(createInterface({ input: createReadStream(fname) }), 50,
        (err, msg) => err == null ? callback(void 0, msg) : raise(err));
};
```

For one, I'm worried that `callb` can be called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what I mentioned in my comment about race conditions not being a problem you should worry about, in my testing of your method I found your code had a few errors.
(Also, I had to change import to const for my environment, but depending on yours you probably don't)

You have a callback function that logs whether the stream is "finished" or has an error, instead why not use that callback to also get the `k` lines you've read? Not a complicated change.

The numbers correspond to places in the code that needed to be changed.

1. Added a call to your callback function that gets passed into `processLargeFile`
2. I couldn't find the `'end'` event listed on the readline docs, so I changed it to `'close'` and included another call to `drainAndProcess` so that whatever lines are leftover will also be processed.
3. Your callback took an error and message as parameter, but now since it also takes the result

Hope this helps.

```
const 
    { createInterface }         = require('readline'),
    { createReadStream }        = require('fs')
;

const processLargeFile = (rl, k, callback) => {
    const a = [];
    const drainAndProcess = () =>{ 
        callback(null, a.splice(0, a.length)); //1
    }

    rl.on('line', line => {
        a.push(line);
        a.length == k && drainAndProcess();  
    });

    rl.on('error', error => callback(error, null));
    rl.on('close', () => drainAndProcess()); // 2
};

processLargeFile(createInterface({
            input: createReadStream('huge_file.csv')
        }), 
        15,
        (err, result) => console.info(err || result) // 3
    );
```

The benefit of doing it this way is that now `processLargeFile` can take any callback as a parameter and send every k lines to said callback.

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't the `close` => `drainAndProcess` line call the `callback`? - Also in my first code example answer, I did ensure `drainAndProcess` was called on the final event. Hmm, maybe the event is `close` and that's why things weren't working cleanly? - So the `a.length === k && drainAndProcessLine()` is guaranteed [sync] of the lines, i.e.: no more lines will be read until it finishes executing?

Comment: In this case `drainAndProcess` slices the array. You could make a few adjustments to this to make it more streamlined as well. The `close` listener could also just pass `a` to the callback directly. The answer to whether or not it's guaranteed I wouldn't know without looking at the code or doing some black box testing, but this more than likely won't be an issue ever. But if you really, really want to make sure your code doesn't break, simply change it to `a.length >= k` and then use `a.splice(0, k)`. This will always get the appropriate amount of lines regardless of the size of a.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative - this time using [`fs.createReadStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options); [through2-concurrent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/through2-concurrent); and [`stream.Transform`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform):

```typescript
import { Transform, TransformOptions } from 'stream';
import { createReadStream } from 'fs';
import * as through2Concurrent from 'through2-concurrent';
import { map } from 'async';

class ParseHandleTsvTransform extends Transform {
    private header: string[];
    private lengths: number[] = [];
    private iterator: (parsed_rows: Array<{}>, cb: (err: Error) => void) => void;

    constructor(options: TransformOptions, iterator: (parsed_rows: Array<{}>,
                cb: (err: Error) => void) => void) {
        super(options);
        this.iterator = iterator;
    }

    public _transform(chunk: Buffer, encoding: string,
                      callb: (err?: Error, res?: Buffer | string) => void) {
        if (!Buffer.isBuffer(chunk))
            return callb(new TypeError(`Expected buffer got: ${typeof chunk}`));
        const rows: string[][] = chunk.toString('utf-8').split('\n').map(
                                                           row => row.split('\t'));
        if (typeof this.header === 'undefined') {
            this.header = rows.shift();
            return callb();
        } else {
            const parsed_rows: Array<{}> = rows.map(row =>
               row.reduce((o, v, i) => Object.assign(o, {[this.header[i]]: v}),{});
            map(parsed_rows, this.iterator, (e: Error) => callb(e));
            // this.iterator(parsed_rows, (e: Error) => callb(e));
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
const processTsv = (fname, callback) =>
    createReadStream(fname)
        .pipe(new ParseHandleTsvTransform({}, asyncDrainAndProcess))
        .pipe(through2Concurrent.obj(
            { maxConcurrency: 10 },
            (chunk, enc, callb) => callb()))
        /* alt: call over here ^, the non-parsing (processing) func: 
           `asyncDrainAndProcess`,
           potentially using the full pattern with `.on('data')` */
        .on('end', () => callback());
```

Or to flesh out the simpler solution:

```
const processTsv = (fname: string, callback: (e?: Error, r?: string) => void) =>
    createReadStream(fname)
        .pipe(through2Concurrent.obj(
            { maxConcurrency: 10 },
            (chunk: Buffer, enc: string, callb: (error?: Error) => void) => {
                if (!Buffer.isBuffer(chunk)) return callb(
                    new TypeError(`Expected buffer got: ${typeof chunk}`));

                const rows: string[][] = chunk.toString('utf-8').split('\n').map(
                                                           row => row.split('\t'));
                if (typeof header === 'undefined')
                    header = rows.shift();

                const parsed_rows: Array<{}> = rows.map(row =>
                  row.reduce((o, v, i) => Object.assign(o, {[header[i]]: v}), {}));

                map(parsed_rows, asyncDrainAndProcess, (e: Error, r) => callb(e));
            }))
        .on('end', () => callback());
```